# Intermittent pg8000.exceptions.InterfaceError in Cloud Run to Cloud SQL Postgres

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

- Experiencing intermittent occurrences of **pg8000.exceptions.InterfaceError** when attempting to establish connections from Cloud Run to a Postgres Server managed by Cloud SQL.
- Errors occur once or twice every 2-5 days.
- Setup operates on a public network without using a private VPC.
- Tech stack includes PostgreSQL 11 and Python 3.7.
- Checked container stats: CPU and memory usage remain around 60% before a new container is spun up.
- No instances observed where the database connection pool or container connection pool got exhausted.

Here's a snippet of the code responsible for managing our database connection pool, utilizing the Google connector:

```
class DatabaseConnection:
    _instance = None
    pool: Engine = None

    def __new__(cls):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super(DatabaseConnection, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls._instance

    @classmethod
    def initialize_pool(cls):
        if cls.pool is None:
            try:
                settings = Settings()

                # Initialize Cloud SQL Connector
                connector = Connector()

                def getconn() -> pg8000.dbapi.Connection:
                    # Use the connector for Cloud SQL
                    return connector.connect(
                        settings.DB_CONNECTION_NAME,
                        "pg8000",
                        user=settings.DB_USER,
                        password=settings.DB_PASSWORD,
                        db=settings.DB_NAME,
                        ip_type=IPTypes.PUBLIC,
                    )

                # Use 'creator' to integrate Cloud SQL Connector with SQLAlchemy
                cls.pool = create_engine(
                    "postgresql+pg8000://",
                    creator=getconn,
                    pool_size=10,
                    max_overflow=1,
                    pool_timeout=30,
                    pool_recycle=1080,
                    pool_pre_ping=True,
                )
                print("Database pool initialized")
            except Exception as e:
                print("Failed to initialize database pool")
                traceback.print_exc()

    @classmethod
    def dispose_pool(cls):
        if cls.pool is not None:
            cls.pool.dispose()
            cls.pool = None
            print("Database pool disposed")

    def get_connection(self):
        if self.pool:
            return self.pool.connect()
        raise SQLAlchemyError("Database pool not initialized")
```

My FastAPI code initializes the pool during startup and get_connection() method is called in each route:

```
@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    # Initialize the database connection pool
    DatabaseConnection.initialize_pool()


@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def shutdown_event():
    # Dispose of the database connection pool
    DatabaseConnection.dispose_pool()
```

Example route where get_connection() is being called:

```
    with DatabaseConnection().get_connection() as postgre_db_connection:
        query_string = text(
            "SELECT * FROM public.brand_data"
        )
        res = postgre_db_connection.execute(query_string)
        query_result_single_row = res.fetchone()
```

Despite my best efforts, the randomness of this error has made it challenging to reproduce consistently, which, in turn, has made debugging efforts equally elusive.

If anyone has encountered similar issues or has expertise in this area, your guidance and suggestions would be immensely appreciated. Additionally, if there are any specific details or logs you require to assist me further, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Cloud Run instances receive CPU cycles while processing an HTTP request. Once the request completes, Cloud Run can idle the CPU to zero. I guess your app has connections open in between requests. The connections are failing due to no CPU time. As a test enable CPU Always Allocated. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation If that solves your problem, then your connection pooling code will need to either handle connection errors or close/reopen connections between requests.

Comment: I thought that too, but I have enabled pool_pre_ping which should Ideally pre-ping the db and if the db is unreachable then it should refresh the connection. Moreover, the actual connection, get_connection() is being called inside the routes (i.e. when the API is called and CPU time is allocated) while only the pool is created when the application starts.  Do you still think the CPU scaling is the issue?
Since it takes 2-5 days to reproduce in general and 'always allocated CPU' has cost implications, I didn't want to try without any logical explanation. Thanks for your time

Comment: I am guessing but it is an educated guess based on years of working with Cloud Run. There are other tests you can make such as removing your pooling code and opening/closing connections as required. I provided a link that gives you more details. TCP connections left open will fail without CPU time being allocated.

Comment: The Python Connector team is aware of this issue. Other customers have reported this problem ([example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector/issues/1022)). We are working on a solution under [issue #805](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector/issues/805). Meanwhile, enabling "CPU always allocated" would fix it.